# C++, template-template параметры функций

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Только только начал изучать C++, базовый python.
Написал следующий код (текст split не привожу, с ним пока проблем нет):

```
template <template<typename> typename C>
void Print(const C<std::string> &container) {
    for (const std::string &path : container) {
        std::cout << path << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {

    std::string path = "/root/tests/01.a";
    char separator = '/';

    std::deque<std::string> result = split(path, separator);
    Print(result);


    return 0;
}
```

В main в дальнейшем собираюсь использовать Print для вывода элементов set'а. Сейчас пытаюсь вывести элементы дека. Но точно элементы и дека и множества имеют тип string. Поэтому мне нужны template-template параметры для функции Print. Однако компилятор ругается на строку

```
Print(result);
```

Пишет- "отсутствуют экземпляры шаблон функции "Print", соответствующие списку аргументов"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку на самом деле дек имеет *два* шаблонных параметра, попробуйте так:

```
template <template<typename T, typename = std::allocator<T>> typename C>
void Print(const C<std::string> &container) {
    for (const std::string &path : container) {
        std::cout << path << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то оно должно было работать и в случае, когда количество параметров шаблона не совпадает (если только компилятор не clang, который по-умолчанию работает в режиме совместимости со старыми стандартами отвергает такое). А еще искусственно ограничивать область применимости шаблона наверное не стоит.

Comment: @user7860670 Не буду спорить, но в этом варианте код реально не работал, например, на VС++2022 (при использовании последнего стандарта), так что я воспользовался старым методом, описанным Вандевурдом.

Answer (score 1):

В этом примере нет необходимости где-то указывать нижележащий тип элемента контейнера или количество параметров шаблона контейнера:

```
void Print(auto const & container)
{
    for (auto const & item: container)
    {
        ::std::cout << item << ::std::endl;
    }
}
```